# How to create a dynamic gradient background 2d in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and for my project I need a gradient background which changes after a certain amount of time. I searched a lot and not able to get it . Can anyone please explain me step by step with respective coding and procedures.  Reference to this type of background is the mobile game stack

Comment: Could it be possible that you upload an image that describe your gradient background? To me, it feels there are many ways to interpret your question.

Comment: Anyway is better for me because I don't have enough knowledge about these.  It would be much useful if you provide answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it normaly by create 2 background. After a certain amount of time just fade old background and enable new background. Code example:

```
void ChangeBackground()
{
     newImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     StartCoroutine(FadeImage(0.1f));
}

IEnumerator FadeImage(float speedStep)
{
     Color newColor = oldImage.color;
     while (newColor.a > 0)
     {
         newColor.a -= speedStep;
         oldImage.color = newColor;
         yield return null;
     }
     oldImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to add this script to the first image?  Or simply create a script.  Can you explain me how to achieve this

Comment: Add this code to your Manager script, you new create two Image is oldImage and newImage in scene. Whenever you want change background call function ChangeBackground.